# Forecasting sales for multiple departments using external factors

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting

I have got the weekly sales information for various locations for about 3 years.It has got information for 157 weeks.Also, I have got the probable external factors affecting the sales.I want to forecast sales for each of the location for next 5 weeks taking into account the other independent factors impact.

[Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bx_EVbbAkrHMcWxFc2ZSb0NTcTg/view?usp=sharing) is my data set.

To start with I have written the code for single location and want to develop it for multiple locations and other factors.

It might be possible that all the factors may not influence the sales.My idea to find important drivers for sales and then use them in forecasting.

Here is my code on some sample data (random):

> s.date <- c(2011,46)
>   sales <- ts(mystore$Sales, start=s.date,frequency=52)

```
sales

Time Series:
Start = c(2011, 46) 
End = c(2014, 46) 
Frequency = 52 
  [1] 357 429 256 131 497 389 265 360 126 401 205 294 173 121 446 333 142 361 119
 [20] 228 396 386 149 398 333 349 274 269 174 298 115 193 289 468 494 295 440 482
 [39] 328 379 337 491 331 182 279 497 239 434 462 119 167 133 145 251 199 428 472
 [58] 193 448 480 154 244 108 150 173 273 357 277 219 216 211 340 101 192 309 281
 [77] 423 373 135 354 179 459 500 445 259 341 325 167 335 431 322 140 188 430 238
 [96] 299 204 350 120 262 193 433 159 457 216 487 239 242 281 207 440 386 339 490
[115] 225 223 208 322 279 408 312 168 249 438 242 241 369 214 383 310 487 382 465
[134] 480 127 394 274 335 369 332 145 210 265 467 115 372 447 270 440 278 122 477
[153] 353 360 451 309 347

> fit_sales <- auto.arima(sales)
> forecast_sales <- forecast(fit_sales,5)

> summary(forecast_sales)

Forecast method: ARIMA(0,0,0)(1,0,0)[52] with non-zero mean

Model Information:
Series: sales 
ARIMA(0,0,0)(1,0,0)[52] with non-zero mean 

Coefficients:
        sar1  intercept
      0.0630   303.2885
s.e.  0.0969     9.5327

sigma^2 estimated as 13012:  log likelihood=-966.56
AIC=1939.11   AICc=1939.27   BIC=1948.28

Error measures:
                      ME     RMSE      MAE       MPE     MAPE      MASE      ACF1
Training set -0.01696482 114.0691 97.73952 -19.54967 42.19241 0.7709323 0.0365932

Forecasts:
         Point Forecast    Lo 80    Hi 80    Lo 95    Hi 95
2014.885       314.8688 168.6833 461.0543 91.29737 538.4402
2014.904       299.2361 153.0506 445.4216 75.66467 522.8075
2014.923       299.4252 153.2397 445.6107 75.85377 522.9966
2014.942       301.8836 155.6981 448.0691 78.31214 525.4550
2014.962       297.2190 151.0335 443.4045 73.64754 520.7904

> accuracy(forecast_sales)


    ME     RMSE      MAE       MPE     MAPE      MASE      ACF1

Training set -0.01696482 114.0691 97.73952 -19.54967 42.19241 0.7709323 0.0365932

> plot(forecast_sales)



> forecast_sales



     Point Forecast    Lo 80    Hi 80    Lo 95    Hi 95
2014.885       314.8688 168.6833 461.0543 91.29737 538.4402
2014.904       299.2361 153.0506 445.4216 75.66467 522.8075
2014.923       299.4252 153.2397 445.6107 75.85377 522.9966
2014.942       301.8836 155.6981 448.0691 78.31214 525.4550
2014.962       297.2190 151.0335 443.4045 73.64754 520.7904
```

I would like to know wtether auto arima takes care of seasonality by itself or not (though optimized model is selected)? I'm aware of basic of transformation, stationary tests, differencing for trends, acf, pacf, white noise test for residuals. How should I implement them in my case.

Should I go for any looping?

Answer (score 0):

It does take into account seasonality. Look at the help page for auto.arima under 'D'.

Also, if you have a lot of information, you may try other means of prediction such as random forests, etc. I'm currently forecasting 4 months ahead for a company and my time-series models can't come close to my other models. I use inputs such as what was the revenue today-364. What are the prices? Month of the year. And a lot more. I find I can get more information into a standard model as opposed to an auto.arima.

And also, this isn't really the forum for such a question. I think you want Cross-Validated :).

Comment: Thanks Jason for your inputs.Will definitely look into it.

Comment: Trying to work with stlf function to meet my needs..Any help is greatly appreciated.